# Finding the values of x in an inequality.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, factoring, cubics

Question: Find the values of x such that $6x^3-x^2-10x-3>0$
Source: James S. Rickards Fall Invitational (Algebra II Individual)

I tried substituting $x^2$ for $y$ and solving, but I ended up with $\sqrt{y}$ and it seemed like that approach wouldn't work. So, I tried factoring the expression and got $(x^2-5/3)(6x-1)-4/3>0$, but this way also seems like a dead end. Is there an efficient way to solve this inequality?

Thanks

Comment: A good idea is to graph the function to see if there is a trivial root, once factorized the quadratics can be solved manually.

Answer (score 1):

-1 is a root.

Divide by x+1
or use the rational root theorem
to find the other roots.

Then see where the terms
are positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$6x^3-x^2-10x-3=6x^3+6x^2-7x^2-7x-3x-3=$$
$$=(x+1)(6x^2-7x-3)=(x+1)(2x-3)(3x+1).$$
Can you end it now?

I got:
$$\left(-1,-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cup\left(\frac{3}{2},+\infty\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how did you say $6x^3−x^2−10x−3=6x^3+6x^2−7x^2−7x−3x−3$ was this through intuition or experience of working with similar problems.

Comment: @NJC I just saw that $-1$ is a root of the polynomial, which gives the factor $x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$6x^3-x^2-10x-3=(2x-3)(3x+1)(x+1)$$